# Finding page id of parent form from pop up form

Tags: asp.net-4.0

I have two pages

1. Master page
2. page using the master page

I am opening a pop up using "window.open" in the second page.
I have  textbox control in the second page and trying the find the control in the pop up page using below code.

```
window.opener.document.getElementById('textbox').value
```

This code could not found out the control.

Then I checked the page source of second form and dound out the format of control id. It was like below.

"_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_textbox"

and changed the code to below and got success.
"window.opener.document.getElementById('_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_textbox').value"

My query is -> I am not about this approach. Please correct if i am doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ASP.NET 4.0 you have the option to set ClientIDMode that could help you in this case.
Setting ClientIDMode to "Static" will ensure that your ID value will not be altered by the framework.

In your page where you have textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="MyTextBox" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Then you should be able to get the value by doing something like this:

```
window.opener.document.getElementById('textbox').value
```

Ref: [MSDN - ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx)

Comment: Thank You for the help. +1 for clientIDMode. Got to learn something new today. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that if you use a masterpage the controls of your contentpage will be renamed making it hard to access them from JavaScript.

Use the following code to solve the problem:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textbox" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
```